# Does regex + symbol apply to previous element only?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

In order to match all strings beginning with `04` and only containing digits, will the following work?

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "^04[0-9]+$")
```

Or is another set of brackets necessary?

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "^04([0-9])+$")
```

Comment: Yes, the first will work. To match `041042043` you would explicitly need `^(04[0-9])+` (or more simply `^(04\d)+`)

Answer (score 3):

In `Regex`:

> ***`[character_group]`***
>   Matches any single character in `character_group`.
>
> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.
>
> ***`(subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a ordinal number.
>
> ***`^`***
>   The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
>
> ***`$`***
>   The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the line or string.

so that this code could be helpful:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "^04\d+$")
```

and all of your code works correctly.

Comment: Actually, `(...)` groups are assigned ordinal numbers starting from *one*, the "zeroth group" is always the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

Your first regex is correct, but the second one isn't.  It matches the same things as the first regex, but it does a lot of unnecessary work in the process.  Check it out:

```
Regex.IsMatch("04123", @"^04([0-9])+$")
```

In this example, the `1` is captured in group #1, only to be overwritten by `2` and again by `3`.  It's almost never a good idea to add a quantifier to a capturing group.  For a detailed explanation, read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

But maybe it's precedence rules you're asking about.  Quantifiers have higher precedence than concatenation, so there's no need to isolate the character class with parentheses (if that's what you're doing).